# Constructor fails when called?

Tags: c++, eclipse, constructor, syntax-error

So I'm new to c++ and I am reviewing a friends code for a project. When compiling the project, `Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600` errors out when calling what I believe to be the constructor, if that may even be the appropriate term for it. I'm using Linux GCC toolchain and Gnu Make Builder.

-I have method `arduino::arduino(char* command, int length)` contained in a file arduino.cpp.

-And i call `arduino::arduino((char*)brightness,3)`in another file where the following erros occur.

What do the following errors mean, why does eclipse produce them, and how can I fix them?

- `for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::arduino’ [-fpermissive]`
- `cannot call constructor ‘arduino::arduino’ directly [-fpermissive]`

Again, I'm very new with c++, so explain like I'm five. Thanks!

Comment: Use keywords new to create object. And then it will  implicit call constructor.We should not call constructor directly to create object because you should allocate memory first.

Comment: So a simple replace with "arduino a = new arduino((char*)brightness,3);" fixed most of the errors but now I receive 
"conversion from ‘arduino*’ to non-scalar type ‘arduino’ requested".

Comment: the easy fix to this is `arduino* a = new arduino( (char*)brightness, 3 );`. However, i suggest you read about dynamic memory allocation in c++ and constructors and destructors as well